# How do I dynamically update profile picture URL on Cloud Firestore for a social network app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am building a social network app using Java and Cloud Firestore. Currently, when the user makes a post, I capture his UID and `photoURL` and store it along with the post content and other details in a `Posts` Collection.
So when I render these posts on a `RecyclerView`, I load the profile picture from the stored URL using Glide.
However, the problem with this is that if a user updates his profile picture, it will still show their older picture with the older posts as the `photoUR`L and posts are coupled.
Is there any way to fix this without having to query for the current `photoURL` by UID for every post as that would be quite inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

> However the problem with this is that if a user updates his profile picture, it will still show their older picture with the older posts

That's the correct behavior since you are not updating that as well.

> Is there any way to fix this without having to query for current photoURL by UID for every post as that would be quite inefficient?

No, there is not. There is no automatic update for that. When you are duplicating data, there is one thing that you need to keep in mind. In the same way, you are adding data, you need to maintain it. In other words, if you want to update an item, you need to do it in every place that it exists. So in your case, you should query the database to find every post and update the "old" URL.

There is also another approach, which is instead of storing the URL, simply store a reference to the user. In this way, doesn't matter how many times the user updates the photo, you'll always point to the new photo. However, there's a downside when using this approach because you'll always create an extra document read for every post that you display. So it's a trade between an extra read and holding a reference vs. holding the URL and updating whenever is needed. So it's up to you to estimate which one is better for your app's use-case.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a fixed **GUID** for each user as their photo's name in the storage bucket. Whenever a user changes his photo, you always place it into the storage bucket with the same **GUID** *"You can delete the older one or store it in a Deleted folder with new **GUID**"*, and when you fetch any user document you just ask the storage service for the file's download URL using the user's fixed **GUID** and use it, so you always get the latest fresh URL. By doing this, you will avoid reading 2 documents for each read request, but you will always head to the storage service per read, and that would probably be cheaper than storing URLs and having to update thousands of related documents when a user changes their photo.

Answer (score 0):

Write a server-side sub-routine (e.g. firebase cloud function on google cloud platform) that is triggered whenever a user updates his profile url. This sub-routine should go through your app and update the profile url of the user wherever it appears.

This will ensure consistency in your data. Putting this code server side will keep your client-side code light weight.

Comment: There might be another way to do this; Make the URL of profile picture for a given user fixed - always at the same URL. That way there is no need to update it.

My intuition tells me that this might result in problems with caching, but maybe not.
Could that be a better way to solve the problem?